# Error loading row data from DataTable into localStorage using a custom Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am using the DataTables Jquery plugin and I am trying to create a custom Button plugin using [the documentation on the DataTable website](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html).  where I could load the row data into localStorage.  Let's call this button 'Save Internally'

```
"buttons": [
            {
              text: 'Save Internally',
              action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                var data = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).data();
                localStorage.setItem("datatable1", JSON.stringify(data));
                  }
                }
              ]
```

When I implement and test it, I don't seem to be able to store anything into the localStorage.  I tried console.log-ing the row data with JSON.stringify to see if the data is extractable from the event, but then I get the error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.  Without the JSON.stringify it gives me `Object Object`.

I try to test the row data with

```
                for (var key in data) {
                  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(key);
```

to see if the object has any properties or keys, but it does not.

The way the row is structured in the front-end is as below.

```
<div class="jumbotron container" id="viewtableresult">
<table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

I know that I can only store strings into localStorage, but not knowing the structure of the object, I wouldn't know how to properly stringify the object. I am sure there must be an easy way to be able to store the row data from the DataTable plugin into localStorage.

**Update** : 
I figured out that there is an [API method called](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()) : `buttons.exportdata()`

Using this I changed the code to the following :

```
              text: 'Save Internally',
              action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                var rows = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).data(); //irrelevant now
                var data = table.buttons.exportData( {
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                } );
                console.log( JSON.stringify(data) ) //was able to show the data in strings
                localStorage.setItem("testdata", JSON.stringify(data));
              }
```

and was able to find the data which has a 'header' and 'body' property.  Now I need to figure out how to setItem() this data into localStorage, as it still does not get stored into localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `.data()` you are getting an object with all rows and functions. You only need rows so you should call `.toArray()`.

```
var data = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).data().toArray();
```

I also created jsFiddle example where I am saving to local storage and reading from it: [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/u41ywsk2/)

Relevant code for storing and loading data:

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Export',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
            var data = dt.rows( { selected: true } ).data().toArray();
            var json = JSON.stringify(data)
            localStorage.setItem('exportedData', json);
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Load',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('exportedData'));
            dt.clear();
            dt.rows.add(data).draw();
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Nice! I'll give a upvote for making the right point in terms of showing the data.  But there is one downside which is that if you have two rows, it is separate by a comma, and inside the array, the items have commas.  Also, for some reason I still can't seem to store this into localStorage.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That fixed it.  I'll accept this answer because it solved it.  However, there seems to be also a way to solve this problem using the API method buttons.exportdata()